# Server 18.04 | Daily server connection issues

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, proxy

I have a problem I was not able to figure out by googling:

We recently installed a Ubuntu Server 18.04 on our vmware vSphere. After a few minor keyboard issues on the console and a few not so minor issues with our corporate proxy / man-in-the-middle network, the server is working mostly stable (I had to install a new  root certificate, configure proxies for apt and bash).   It is only operating in our corporate network, no external access possible (which is fine for now / desired).

The remaining problem: Daily between ~8-11 o'clock the server cannot be reached. Neither ping, ssh, docker-hosted apps are accessible. After 11 everything is working fine. I had a look at the server logs, but were not able to find any issues. It may have something to do with daily update routines but I don't know where to look. I already changed a random sleep in `/etc/cron.daily/apt-compat` to 10 seconds (from 1800).

syslog:

```
Jul 11 06:25:01 servername rsyslogd:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.32.0" x-pid="5678" x-info="http://www$
Jul 11 06:54:15 servername systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt upgrade and 
clean activities...
Jul 11 06:54:18 servername systemd[1]: Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
Jul 11 07:17:01 servername CRON[9579]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 11 07:46:28 servername systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt download activities...
Jul 11 07:46:57 servername systemd[1]: Started Daily apt download activities.
Jul 11 08:17:01 servername CRON[9995]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 11 09:17:01 servername CRON[10009]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 11 10:17:01 servername CRON[10022]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 11 10:41:48 servername systemd[1]: Started Session 54 of user user.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Cheers!

Comment: maybe a backup job or similar on the vsphere server?

Comment: @SebastianStark, I think vsphere might be the problem. I wrote a little script pinging the server from another machine and I have fewer problems now. Seems like the server somehow gets hibernated if not actively used. Still waiting on the IT department to have a look into this.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is IP address collision: Someone connects a laptop with the same fixed address of a critical server in some time interval.  I have had that problem several times in my University network. Using the `arping` utility from another server in the same VLAN showed two MAC addresses responding to the same IP, then using the switches admin interface hunted down the physical port used by the culprit and disabled it in the corresponding office switch. Then the user came to report the 'I have no internet' problem ;)